# Python JSON Unicode Error OrderedDict

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I want to be able to view the file in the editor and see an automatically ü.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

fdata = OrderedDict()
fdata[u"Züge"] = 0
fdata[u"Bahnhöfe"] = 0

with open("Desktop/test.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(fdata, outfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in
>   position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

It has something to do with OrderedDict, with a normal dict it works.

Comment: Is the exception occurring only at runtime or you also have difficulty to display the character in a text editor ?

Comment: it occurs when i try json.dumps()

Comment: Can you show us the code that opens 'file'? Have you specified an encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify an encoding when opening the file, so `outfile.encoding` is probably `None`.

> **file.encoding**
>
> The encoding that this file uses. When Unicode strings
>   are written to a file, they will be converted to byte strings using
>   this encoding. In addition, when the file is connected to a terminal,
>   the attribute gives the encoding that the terminal is likely to use
>   (that information might be incorrect if the user has misconfigured the
>   terminal). The attribute is read-only and may not be present on all
>   file-like objects. *It may also be None, in which case the file uses
>   the system default encoding for converting Unicode strings.*

And your system default encoding is apparently ascii.

Instead, open your file with the desired encoding:

```
import codecs
  with codecs.open("test.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once, I've added this line at the top of my .py file and it worked.

```
# coding=utf-8
```